# Calculations per sub-groups and reshape dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, reshape

I am fairly new to dplyr and I would like to do the following calculation.

I have this df, per group (cohort); for each group numerical values related to order_number reference

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
          ~cohort, ~order_number,  ~post,   ~pre,
        "2019-06",             0, 138.86, 163.36,
        "2019-06",             3, 148.54, 174.75,
        "2019-06",             6, 192.52,  226.5,
        "2019-06",             9, 233.32,  283.5,
        "2019-07",             0, 127.81, 150.37,
        "2019-07",             3, 140.16, 164.83,
        "2019-07",             6, 121.51, 142.93,
        "2019-07",             9, 138.71, 162.86
        )

# A tibble: 8 x 4
  cohort  order_number  post   pre
  <chr>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2019-06            0  139.  163.
2 2019-06            3  149.  175.
3 2019-06            6  193.  226.
4 2019-06            9  233.  284.
5 2019-07            0  128.  150.
6 2019-07            3  140.  165.
7 2019-07            6  122.  143.
8 2019-07            9  139.  163.
```

I want to perform these calculations:

1. for each cohort, each post value over the post value of min order
2. for each cohort, each post value over the post value of min order

Aka. at the first step (order 0), I do 139/139 = 1, at the second step (order 1), I do 139/149= 0.93, and so on for each cohort group; for both numeric columns.

Result as follows:

```
df_calc <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                           cohort = c("2019-06", "2019-06", "2019-06", "2019-06",
                                      "2019-07", "2019-07", "2019-07",
                                      "2019-07"),
                     order_number = c(0, 3, 6, 9, 0, 3, 6, 9),
                             post = c(138.86, 148.54, 192.52, 233.32, 127.81, 140.16,
                                      121.51, 138.71),
                              pre = c(163.36, 174.75, 226.5, 283.5, 150.37, 164.83,
                                      142.93, 162.86),
              perc_per_group_post = c(1, 0.93, 0.72, 0.6, 1, 0.91, 1.05, 0.92),
               perc_per_group_pre = c(1, 0.93, 0.72, 0.58, 1, 0.91, 1.05, 0.92)
           )

   cohort order_number   post    pre perc_per_group_post perc_per_group_pre
1 2019-06            0 138.86 163.36                1.00               1.00
2 2019-06            3 148.54 174.75                0.93               0.93
3 2019-06            6 192.52 226.50                0.72               0.72
4 2019-06            9 233.32 283.50                0.60               0.58
5 2019-07            0 127.81 150.37                1.00               1.00
6 2019-07            3 140.16 164.83                0.91               0.91
7 2019-07            6 121.51 142.93                1.05               1.05
8 2019-07            9 138.71 162.86                0.92               0.92
```

And then reshape:

```
df_calc_reshape <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                            cohort = c("2019-06", "2019-06", "2019-06", "2019-06", "2019-07",
                                       "2019-07", "2019-07", "2019-07",
                                       "2019-06", "2019-06", "2019-06", "2019-06",
                                       "2019-07", "2019-07", "2019-07", "2019-07"),
                      order_number = c(0, 3, 6, 9, 0, 3, 6, 9, 0, 3, 6, 9, 0, 3, 6, 9),
                          ret_post = c(1, 0.93, 0.72, 0.6, 1, 0.91, 1.05, 0.92, 1, 0.93, 0.72,
                                       0.58, 1, 0.91, 1.05, 0.92),
                              type = c("perc_per_group_post", "perc_per_group_post",
                                       "perc_per_group_post",
                                       "perc_per_group_post", "perc_per_group_post",
                                       "perc_per_group_post", "perc_per_group_post",
                                       "perc_per_group_post", "perc_per_group_pre",
                                       "perc_per_group_pre", "perc_per_group_pre",
                                       "perc_per_group_pre", "perc_per_group_pre",
                                       "perc_per_group_pre", "perc_per_group_pre",
                                       "perc_per_group_pre")
                   )

    cohort order_number ret_post                type
1  2019-06            0     1.00 perc_per_group_post
2  2019-06            3     0.93 perc_per_group_post
3  2019-06            6     0.72 perc_per_group_post
4  2019-06            9     0.60 perc_per_group_post
5  2019-07            0     1.00 perc_per_group_post
6  2019-07            3     0.91 perc_per_group_post
7  2019-07            6     1.05 perc_per_group_post
8  2019-07            9     0.92 perc_per_group_post
9  2019-06            0     1.00  perc_per_group_pre
10 2019-06            3     0.93  perc_per_group_pre
11 2019-06            6     0.72  perc_per_group_pre
12 2019-06            9     0.58  perc_per_group_pre
13 2019-07            0     1.00  perc_per_group_pre
14 2019-07            3     0.91  perc_per_group_pre
15 2019-07            6     1.05  perc_per_group_pre
16 2019-07            9     0.92  perc_per_group_pre
```

It should be fairly easy with dplyr.

I guess I can use mutate, but I don't know how to group by.
then the result,to reshape it, I would do it with gather; but without the first step I am stuck.

Comment: Can you clarify this: "for each cohort, each post value over the post value of min order". It's unclear how you get 1.00. What do you divide by what?

Comment: at the first step (order 0), I do 139/139 = 1, at the second step (order 1), I do 139/149= 0.93, and so on for each cohort group. Sorry if it was unclear. @PierreLapointe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach which simply follows your logic, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(cohort) %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(c('post', 'pre')), list(new =~ first(.) / .)) %>% 
 select(-c('post', 'pre')) %>% 
 pivot_longer(cols = c('post_new', 'pre_new'), 
              names_to = 'type', 
              values_to = 'ret_post')
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 16 x 4
> # Groups:   cohort [2]
>    cohort  order_number type     ret_post
>    <chr>          <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
>  1 2019-06            0 post_new    1    
>  2 2019-06            0 pre_new     1    
>  3 2019-06            3 post_new    0.935
>  4 2019-06            3 pre_new     0.935
>  5 2019-06            6 post_new    0.721
>  6 2019-06            6 pre_new     0.721
>  7 2019-06            9 post_new    0.595
>  8 2019-06            9 pre_new     0.576
>  9 2019-07            0 post_new    1    
> 10 2019-07            0 pre_new     1    
> 11 2019-07            3 post_new    0.912
> 12 2019-07            3 pre_new     0.912
> 13 2019-07            6 post_new    1.05 
> 14 2019-07            6 pre_new     1.05 
> 15 2019-07            9 post_new    0.921
> 16 2019-07            9 pre_new     0.923
> ```

You can further generalize the long format via `pivot_longer()` arguments. You can find more infrmation [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html)